# User defined type in complex query parameter using AngularJS UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got a complex query parameter in UI-Router in Angular. It is list of optional items that user can choose in a page.

In example:

```
params = {
  price_min: 20,
  price_max: 200,
  shipment_method: "stationary",
  basic_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...),
  complex_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...),
  another_one_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...)
}
```

Some of them are of my custom type, I registered by:

```
$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('inventoryType', InventoryTypeFactory.getInventoryType())
```

My state configuration looks like:

```
.state('chooseInventory', {
  url: '/inventory?tab&params',
  templateUrl: 'inventory.html',
  controller: 'InventoryController'
})
```

Is it possible to make Angular use of my type automatically when serialising into url or deserialising from?

My custom type specification provides either "is" method and "regex" field but it seems not to do the job.

Of course, I can write simply:

```
url: '/inventory?tab?{item1:inventoryType}?{item2:inventoryType}...'
```

But my "params" object can actually contain lots of them

Answer (score 0):

By configuring your state like this:

```
    .state('chooseInventory', {
      url: '/inventory',
      params = {
        price_min: 20,
        price_max: 200,
        shipment_method: "stationary",
        basic_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...),
        complex_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...),
        another_one_inventory_intem: (...some custom type...)
      },  
      templateUrl: 'inventory.html',
      controller: 'InventoryController'
})
```

you should be able to access the passed parameters in your controller like so
`$stateParams.price_min`

One way to change state with params is: `$state.go('chooseInventory',{price_min: 10})`

Comment: I forgot mentioning, that it is important to us to have those parameters visible in the url, so users can exchange references to partially filled forms.
Our custom defined type has encode/decode methods so it'll be nice to make framework use of them. Default angular serialization, exposing internal object structure isn't good neither.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share, how I solved my problem myself.

I have just taken a look how Angular handles JS objects by default, so I have registered another one type based on that concept, to handle my list of query params:

```
var inventory = InventoryTypeFactory.getInventoryType();
var getQueryParamListType = function() {
  return {
    encode: (function(_this) {
      return function(object) {
        var innerConvert = function(data) {
          var key, value;
          var processed = {};
          for (key in data) {
            value = data[key];
            if (inventory.is(value)) {
              processed[key] = inventory.encode(value);
            } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
              processed[key] = encodeString(value);
            } else if (angular.isObject(value)) {
              processed[key] = innerConvert(value);
            }
          }
          return processed;
        };
        return angular.toJson(innerConvert(object));
      };
    })(this),
    decode: (function(_this) {
      return function(string) {
        var innerConvert = function(data) {
          var key, value;
          var processed = {};
          for (key in data) {
            value = data[key];
            if (new RegExp(inventory.pattern).test(value)) {
              processed[key] = inventory.decode(value);
            } else if (typeof value === 'string') {
              processed[key] = decodeString(value);
            } else if (angular.isObject(value)) {
              processed[key] = innerConvert(value);
            }
          }
          return processed;
        };
        return innerConvert(angular.fromJson(string));
      };
    })(this),
    equals: angular.equals,
    is: angular.isObject,
    pattern: /[^\/]*/
  };
};
```